# android - web view is not fitted in the screen

Tags: android, webview

I am trying load the GIF image in the web view. It's loaded perfectly but i want to fit it within screen. I mean, i don't want the scrollbars(Horizontal/vertical). Horizontal sideit is fitted but in vertical side it is not fitted. Please can anyone help me.

Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Using Web view
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView view = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.animationview);

    // Only hide the scrollbar, not disables the scrolling:
    view.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    view.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);

    // Settings
    WebSettings settings = view.getSettings();
    settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    settings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);

    // Load the GIF
    String strUrl = "file:///android_asset/lk_animation.gif";
    view.loadUrl(strUrl);
}
```

}

Layout

```
< LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


< WebView
    android:id="@+id/animationview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

< / LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Naresh, how did you solved this? I am facing the similar problem. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

> set zoom false

```
webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
```

> use these method so that you can control the zoom so that image will fit into the screen.

webview.getSettings(). setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.CLOSE);

webview.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.FAR);

webview.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(WebSettings.ZoomDensity.MEDIUM);